# I want to Create One to Many Relationship | with If Condition | (Category has many Subcategories)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-7

I want to create a Category, if they have a `parent categoryId` then update the parent id, and `categoryName` on the `subcategory Table`. if they have not parent id then, it saves on the `parent Category table` with category name. Can you Correct my Relationship Code? I think it is wrong.  and Very Thank you to Help me

in category Model (parent)

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function subcategories(){
        return $this->hasMany(Subcategory::class);
    }
}
```

In the Subcategory Model,

```
class Subcategory extends Model

    {
        public function category(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
        }
    }
```

In controller,

```
public function store(Request $request){
    //dd($request->categoryid);
    if($request->categoryid){ 
       $subcategory = new Subcategory();
       $subcategory->name = $request->subcatname;
       $subcategory->save(); 

     $category = $request->categoryid;
       //dd($category);
       $subcategory->category()->attach($category); 

    } 
       $category = new Category();
       $category->name = $request->catname;
       $category->save();
    }
```

in dd($request)

```
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: array:3 [▼
      "_token" => "z8kJy323B1Af27dKfHRHRHW1ON9NKHuP8DmYW06e"
      "subcatname" => "Samsung"
      "categoryid" => "1"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Post your data in the same format will be helpful like if you want to submit a category then post only the name of the category or if you want to create subcategory then post data will categoryid and name of the subcategory and then you can create your record by this way using laravel eloquent mapping.

```
if($request->categoryid)
{ 
   $category= Category::find($request->categoryid);
   $subcategory = $category->subcategories()->create($request->all());
} 
else{
  $category = new Category();
  $category = $category->create($request->all());
}
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `subcategories` (`category_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, 2020-10-26 06:47:09, 2020-10-26 06:47:09))

I got this error.

Comment: in your post data  change your `sucatname` to `name` and then check @RoomalJayaratne

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($request->exists('categoryid')) {
   $category = Category::findOrFail($request->categoryid)
                ->subcategories()->create($request->all());
} else {
   $category = Category::create($request->all());
}
```